# refresh selector when data is changed redux-orm

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I use ***redux-orm*** where in i create a Author model and add 5 items to it mainly age and name as its properties.

These 5 author items are got via a web api call which gets dispatched in the **componentDidMount / componentWillMount** (tried both) handler for the react component.

I have created a selector which returns a list of authors .

I have then connected this selector with a property using react connect.

When i run the app the mapStateToProps gets called before the network web api call is made in the the **componentDidMount / componentWillMount** and the selector will contain no values.

Now onclick of a button or any other event how do i gets this selector be refreshed to contain new values ?

***Make web api call in component***

[image: Make web api call in component]

***Use react-redux connect to map***

[image: Use react-redux connect to map]

***Selector to get list of all Authors***

[image]